# Timescale missing on the module as other modules have it Verilator error

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip, verilator

I am trying to add an accelerator to the rocket chip framework through the MMIO peripheral. I went through the GCD example and was able to build the basic GCD code. I then replaced the GCD with an accelerator which has it's own Config, Parameters and Field information. Now when I try to pass this information to the rocket chip there is a name clash with the `freechips.rocketchip.config.{Parameters, Field, Config}`. I tried specifying the whole path i.e; `accelerator.util.conig.Parameters` to distinguish it from `freechips.rocketchip.config.Parameters` but it still gave me the same error. When I remove my accelerator configs and parameters and pass simple hand made parameters the build is successful, however, when I add my config I get `%Error-TIMESCALEMOD` and this error is in the generated file which I am not modifying. I tried a work around by altering my verilator options but that goes down a rabbit hole of errors. I have narrowed down the problem to the fact that this is being caused because I am using two different configs both of which have their own Config.scala file [shown here](https://github.com/chipsalliance/api-config-chipsalliance/tree/fd8df1105a92065425cd353b6855777e35bd79b4/design/craft/src/config) Is there a way to fix this problem? I have attached the error with this question.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some information about what your top level config looks like and what config you build off of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a blackbox, not sure why it was giving me that error, but yes we can mix two different configs having different util.config files. We just have to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Mind elaborating on the solution to the error?

Comment: You need to source your verilog files for the blackboxes properly. Most often this is the reason for this kind of an error.